# Count visible rows from table within a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a two unique div id's with a the same table ID inside of them.

```
<div id = 'currentItems'><table id = 'allItems'></table></div>
```

is displaying the current table

```
<div id = 'newItems'><table id = 'allItems'></table></div>
```

is displaying the refreshed table (via jquery load)

I currently have this jquery function which grabs all visible table rows. It works great, except I have TWO tables with the same ID.

```
 var countVisibleRows = $('tr').filter(function() {
     return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';
 }).length;
```

Is there any way to specify the above function to only look for visible TRs within the div id = 'newItems'? Keeping in mind the div and table may be hidden, I just want to count the rows that *would* be visible.

Comment: Well ids need to be singular so that is invalid....

Comment: One of your tables can not be accessed by ID. One of the IDs will overwrite or block the other one. I don't know which though. You should make a class if you need both tables to have the same identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So use the div id and visible selector

```js
var trsC = $('#currentItems table tbody tr:visible')
console.log(trsC.length);
var trsN = $('#newItems table tbody tr:visible')
console.log(trsN.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="currentItems">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td></tr>
      <tr hidden><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<div id="newItems">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>5</td></tr>
      <tr hidden><td>6</td></tr>
      <tr hidden><td>7</td></tr>
      <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If OP replaces the `allItems` Ids with classes; then, I believe `#currentItems table` could become `.allItems`. That would; then, access all visible rows from both tables.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you so much! I tried to mark your answer Correct but it says I'm too new. Thank you for your help.